# Any free AirPlay receivers for Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, airplay

Are there any free AirPlay receivers that receive both audio and video (if possible mirroring) also, in Ubuntu?

I have worked with Kodi, but it is not working for iOS 9.3.5, even after enabling iOS 9 support in it.

There are quite few for Windows, but are there any for Ubuntu which work without the need of Wine.

Comment: What is an "AirPlay"?

Comment: @xangua With AirPlay, you can wirelessly stream videos, music, and photos from your iPhone.